# A problem about recursion formula of de Casteljau algorithm

Tags: recursion, algorithm

I use *Mathematica* to implement the [de Casteljau algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm)

$$\vec{P}_{k,i}(u_0)=(1-u_0)\vec{P}_{k-1,i}(u_0)+u_0\vec{P}_{k-1,i+1}(u_0)$$

The graphics that de Casteljau algorithm generated as follows:

[image: diagram]

#### My trial

```
(*The recursion formula*)
P[k_, i_, u0_] :=
 (1 - u0) P[k - 1, i, u0] + u0 P[k - 1, i + 1, u0]
(*Initial values*)
P[0, 0, 2/5] = {0, 0};
P[0, 1, 2/5] = {2, 4}; 
P[0, 2, 2/5] = {4, 5};
P[0, 3, 2/5] = {6, 0};

ptsData = Table[P[k, i, 2/5], {k, 0, 3}, {i, 0, 3 - k}];
pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}};
Graphics[
  Join[Point /@ ptsData, Line /@ ptsData, {Red, BezierCurve[pts]}]]
```

It works well.

[image: yes it does]

So I packed these codes to a function `deCasteljau[]`

```
deCasteljau[pts_, u_] :=
 Module[{p, ptsdata, n},
  n = Length@pts - 1;
  Table[p[0, j, u], {j, 0, n}] = pts;
  p[k_, i_, u0_] :=(1 - u0) p[k - 1, i, u0] + u0 p[k - 1, i + 1, u0];
  ptsdata = Table[p[k, i, u], {k, 0, n}, {i, 0, n - k}];

 Graphics[
   Join[Point /@ ptsdata, Line /@ ptsdata, {Red, BezierCurve[pts]}]]
]
```

However, it failed.

```
deCasteljau[{{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}}, 2/5]
```

[image: errors]

I felt that the main question is the recursion formula `p[k_, i_, u0_] :=(1 - u0) p[k - 1, i, u0] + u0 p[k - 1, i + 1, u0];` But I cannot deal with it by myself smoothly.

#### Question:

How to revise it?(Or how to avoid using the ***recursion formula***. Namely, using *Mathematica* construction to replace it)

---

#### Edit

Thanks for kale help

When I input

```
 ?j
```

> ```
>  Global`j
> ```

[image: result]

In general, the variable `j` in construction `Table[p[0, j, u], {j, 0, n}]` should be local.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Set` has attributes `HoldFirst`. So when we evaluate `a=2` (aka `Set[a,2]`), `a` is held until the rhs is evaluated.

In your example, the issue is setting your initial points with `Table[p[0, j, u], {j, 0, n}] = pts;`. We can add `Evaluate` and get along with our business. This forces the `Table` command to evaluate first before proceeding with `Set`.

```
deCasteljau[pts_, u_] := Module[{p, ptsdata, n}, n = Length@pts - 1;
 Evaluate[Table[p[0, j, u], {j, 0, n}]] = pts;
 p[k_, i_, u0_] := (1 - u0) p[k - 1, i, u0] + u0 p[k - 1, i + 1, u0];
 ptsdata = Table[p[k, i, u], {k, 0, n}, {i, 0, n - k}];
 Graphics[
 Join[Point /@ ptsdata, Line /@ ptsdata, {Red, BezierCurve[pts]}]]
]

deCasteljau[{{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}}, 2/5]
```

> [image]

Comment: +1, Could you tell me why `j` in `Evaluate[Table[p[0, j, u], {j, 0, n}]] = pts;` is Global, not local

Comment: @Tangshutao It's not Global. It's localized inside of the `Table` function. I'm definitely not an expert in this but it appears the presence of `j` is made known, but no values are assigned. `Table` effectively uses `Block` so even *if* `j` had a global value assigned, the `Table` construct would still work as desired.

Comment: The `syntax color`of `j` is black when `j` has a value outsize

Comment: @Tangshutao But the `Table` construct still works, meaning (IMO) it's a bug with the syntax coloring engine.

Comment: So @kale I use the `P[0, #, u] & /@ Range[0, n]` to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Although I cannot understand why `j` in `Evaluate[Table[p[0, j, u], {j, 0, n}]] = pts` is **Local**, I use `P[0, #, u] & /@ Range[0, n]` to avoid using `Table[p[0, j, u], {j, 0, n}]`

With the help of *kale*, I improve my function `deCasteljauPlot[]` as below:

```
deCasteljauPlot[pts : {{_, _} ..}, u_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
 Module[{P, ptsCoordi, n}, 
  n = Length@pts - 1;  
  (*Assign initial values *)
  Evaluate[P[0, #, u] & /@ Range[0, n]] = pts;
  (*recursion formula*)
  P[k_, i_, u0_] := (1 - u0) P[k - 1, i, u0] + u0 P[k - 1, i + 1, u0];
  (*generate the coordinates of points*)
  ptsCoords = Table[P[k, i, u], {k, 0, n}, {i, 0, n - k}];
  Graphics[
   Join[
    {PointSize[.012], Red}, Point /@ ptsCoords, {Black}, 
     Line /@ ptsCoords, {Red, BezierCurve[pts]}],
  (*generate the names of points*)
    Epilog ->
     Text @@@
      Join[
       Thread@
        {Table[Style[Subscript["P", i], 12, Blue], {i, 0, n}], 
         # + {.2, .2} & /@pts},
       Thread@
        {Flatten@
          Table[Style[Subscript["P", k, i], 12, Purple], 
                {k, 1, n}, {i,0, n - k}],             
          # + {.2, .2} & /@ Flatten[Rest@ptsCoordi, 1]}], opts]
  ]
```

**Test**

```
 deCasteljauPlot[{{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}}, 2/5, 
                  PlotRange -> {{-1, 9}, {-1, 6}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Or we can `Manipulate` to look the process

```
Manipulate[
  deCasteljauPlot[
    {{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}}, u, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 7}, {-1, 6}}, ImageSize -> 400], 
  {{u, .2}, 0, 1}
]
```

[image]