# How to deal with the condition $u_i=u_{i+1}$ in B-Spline basis function?

Tags: functions, splines

The defintion of B-Spline basis function as shown below:

Let $\vec{U}=\{u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ a nondecreasing sequence of real numbers,i.e, $u_i\leq u_{i+1}\quad i=0,1,2\ldots m-1$

$$N_{i,0}(u)=
\begin{cases}
   1 & u_i\leq u<u_{i+1}\\
   0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
$$
$$N_{i,p}(u)=\frac{u-u_i}{u_{i+p}-u_i}N_{i,p-1}(u)+\frac{u_{i+p+1}-u}{u_{i+p+1}-u_{i+1}}N_{i+1,p-1}(u)
$$

Although I know that *Mathematica* owns a *built-in* function [`BSplineBasis`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineBasis.html?q=BSplineBasis),
however, I would like to write my auxiliay function $N_{i,p}(u)$ to learn the **`NURBS`** theory and *Mathematica programming*.

#### NBSpline

Alogrithm:

> [image]

```
 (*=======================Caculate N[i,0](u)================================*)
 NBSpline[i_Integer, 0, u_Symbol, U : {Sequence[_] ..}] /; 
  i <= Length[U] - 2 :=
  Piecewise[
   {{1, U[[i + 1]] <= u < U[[i + 2]]},
    {0, u < U[[i + 1]] || u >= U[[i + 2]]}}]

 (*=======================Caculate N[i,p](u)================================*)

 NBSpline[i_Integer, p_Integer, u_Symbol, U : {Sequence[_] ..}?OrderedQ] /;
  p > 0 && i + p <= Length[U] - 2 :=
  Module[{ini},
   ini = Table[NBSpline[j, 0, u, U], {j, i, i + p}];
   First@Simplify@
    Nest[
     Dot @@@
      (Thread@
       {Partition[#, 2, 1],
        With[{m = i + p - Length@# + 1},
         Table[
          {(u - U[[k + 1]])/(U[[k + m + 1]] - U[[k + 1]]),
           (U[[k + m + 2]] - u)/(U[[k + m + 2]] - U[[k + 2]])}, {k, i, i + Length@# - 2}]]}) &,
   ini, p]
]
```

**Test**

```
NBSpline[1, 3, u, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}] // TraditionalForm
```

> [image]

In my function `NBSpline` I avoid the condition $u_i=u_{i+1}$, because it will occured the case $\frac{0}{0}$

In the book **"*The NURBS book*"**, it defines this quotient $\frac{0}{0}$ to be zero.

#### Question

How to deal with the condition $\frac{0}{0}$ that I sometimes need to set it to 0 ? Namely, How to deal with the condition $u_i=u_{i+1}$ in B-Spline basis function?

Comment: `Quiet@Block[{Indeterminate = 0},
  0/0]`

Comment: @Kuba,Thanks for your suggestion sincerely!:-) Then I execute your code,  `NBSpline[1, 3, u, {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7}]` give a result without warning, however, `NBSpline[1, 3, u, {1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7}]` and `NBSpline[1, 3, u, {1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 7}]` give the warning informtion `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>`

Comment: Perhaps one should approach the problem of understanding $N_{i,p}$ by asking how to deal with the condition $u_i = u_{i+1}$.  Redefining `0/0` is not the only way, and, given your comment, it's probably not a good way.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I got it!Thanks!

Comment: I guess you might be interested in this book: *Curves and Surfaces for CAGD - A Practical Guide* by Gerald Farin.

Comment: @Silvia Yes, I have borrowed that book from the the library of my university. However, I discovered that it is different from "The NURBS Book" in writing style, so I have been reading the latter book:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I'm recently interested in using Bezier triangular patch as a universal surface approximating tool. It would be really nice to hear your advice.

Comment: @Silvia In *"The NURBS Book"*, the Bezier triangular patch was not discussed by Les piegl. So I have no knowledge about that subject. But I know that subject was written in this book: **Bézier and B-Spline Techniques**

Comment: @Silvia Please see [here](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/productFlyer/productFlyer_978-3-642-07842-2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-1297-174087538-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to deal with repeated entries in `U`.  One can define a function to compute the coefficient, using one rule when $u_i = u_j$ and the general formula otherwise.  One might put extra conditions on the patterns in `coeff` below, but if the function is called only within `NBSpline`, then one might assume the conditions are met.

```
ClearAll[coeff];
coeff[u_, i_, j_, U_] /; U[[i]] == U[[j]] := 0;
coeff[u_, i_, j_, U_] := (u - U[[i]])/(U[[j]] - U[[i]])
```

Then change the definition of `NBSpline` for `p != 0` as follows.

```
NBSpline[i_Integer, p_Integer, u_Symbol, 
   U : {Sequence[_] ..}?OrderedQ] /; p > 0 && i + p <= Length[U] - 2 :=
  Module[{ini}, ini = Table[NBSpline[j, 0, u, U], {j, i, i + p}];
  First@Simplify@
    Nest[Dot @@@ (Thread@{Partition[#, 2, 1], 
          With[{m = i + p - Length@# + 1}, 
           Table[{
             coeff[u, k + 1, k + m + 1, U], 
             coeff[u, k + m + 2, k + 2, U]},
            {k, i, i + Length@# - 2}]]}) &, ini, p]]
```

Example:

```
NBSpline[1, 3, u, {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The output of `NBSpline[1, 3, u, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}]` agrees with the output in the question.

*P.S.* The pattern `U : {Sequence[_] ..}?OrderedQ` is equivalent to `U_List?OrderedQ`.  You might want a check that restricts `U` to be a list of numbers, since an ordered list of symbols such as `{a, b, c}` passes the `OrderedQ` test.  The pattern `U_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] && OrderedQ[#] &)` is one way.

Comment: +1,Good idea to deal with $u_i=u_{i+1}$:-)

Comment: BTW, Is it possible to make the order of `Piecewise` like $2\leq u<4, 4\leq u<5, 5\leq u<7$, rather than $5\leq u<7, 2\leq u<4, 4\leq u<5$?

Comment: The easiest way would be to sort it afterwards: `MapAt[SortBy[Last], piecewisefn, 1]`, `piecewisefn` is the result of `NBSpline`.  (Use `SortBy[#, Last] &` instead of `SortBy[Last]` if you're using V9 or earlier.)

Comment: I can't get the same result after running your code (version 12.0).

Answer (score 4):

*Is this the behaviour you need?*

### Solution

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, -1] = 1
Protect[Power]
```

### Examples

```
0/0
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Explanation

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Revert to normal

```
Unprotect[Power];
ClearAll[Power];
Protect[Power];
```

Comment: The main probelm is the condition $u_i=u_{i+1}$, your solution can indeed deal with this case.Thanks sincerely!! +1:-)  I have edited my question .