# A problem about sorting final result

Tags: evaluation, sorting

Three days ago, I asked a question about B-Spline Basis fuction [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63192/how-to-deal-with-the-condition-u-i-u-i1-in-b-spline-basis-function)

@Michael E2 given a solution to make the order of interval looks normal

> The easiest way would be to sort it afterwards: MapAt[SortBy[Last], piecewisefn, 1], piecewisefn is the result of NBSpline. (Use SortBy[#, Last] & instead of SortBy[Last] if you're using V9 or earlier.)

**Trial 1**

```
 sortResult[res_] := MapAt[SortBy[#, Last] &, res, 1] /; res != 0
 sortResult[0] := 0;
 knots={1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7};
 sortResult[NBSpline[1, 2, u, knots]]
```

> [image]

**Trial 2**

```
 NBSpline[1, 3, u, {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7}]// MapAt[SortBy[#, Last] &, #, 1] &
```

> [image]

This time, it gives me a normal order $2 \leq u <4, 4 \leq u <5, 5 \leq u <7$

#### Question:

How to revise it ? And can someone give me a *explanation* about this case?

Comment: Do you get the desired result if you change the last line of _Trial 1_  to `tmp = NBSpline[1, 2, u, knots]; sortResult[tmp]; tmp`?

Comment: @kguler, it didn't sort the $interval$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understand your question.  I think you are wondering why **Trial 1** does not work the same as **Trial 2**.  In that case the answer lies with `!=` or [`Unequal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal.html).  The [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) will not match because `!=` does not evaluate when one side is symbolic and the other numeric.  Instead you should use:

```
sortResult[x_ /; x == 0] := 0;
sortResult[res_] := MapAt[SortBy[#, Last] &, res, 1]
```

The first definition will catch all arguments [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) to zero.  See:

- [Using function with multiple definitions in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5149/121)
- [The difference between 0. and 0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6994/121)

Comment: +2, It works well, thanks a lot!:-)