# Could I define 0^0 to be 1?

Tags: numerical-value

Many occasions, where I need to work numerically with functions.
For a variable strictly between 0 and 1, during the optimization, it could become 0.^0 or 0^0, which then become indeterminate.[image]

Is there a way to define this 0^0=1?

What are the possible down side of defining such relationship?

Thanks!

Comment: [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but there is no rush and its a good idea to wait a few hour for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. Better answers may come later.

Comment: I used before Leonid solution `f = Unevaluated[#1^#2] /. HoldPattern[0^0] :> 1 &` [how-to-tell-mathematica-to-replace-0-to-power-0-by-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403626/how-to-tell-mathematica-to-replace-0-to-power-0-by-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of @Michael E2 in [my question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63192/how-to-deal-with-the-condition-u-i-u-i1-in-b-spline-basis-function/63194#answer-63194)

Case $\frac{0}{0}$

In this case,you can define your function like this:

```
func1[a_,b_]:=0 /;b==0
func1[a_,b_]:=a/b
```

**Test**

```
func1[0, 0]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Case$0.^0$

So you can use the `/;` to avoid $0.^0$

```
func2[x_,0]:=1/;x==0||x==0.
func2[x_,y_:0]:=x^y
```

**Test**

```
 func2[0, 0]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
 func2[0., 0]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Answer (score 16):

Yes, by doing this (similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63192/how-to-deal-with-the-condition-u-i-u-i1-in-b-spline-basis-function/63194#answer-63194)):

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0|0., 0|0.] = 1;
Protect[Power];
```

If you want to revert to normal:

```
Unprotect[Power];
ClearAll[Power];
Protect[Power];
```

The downside is that it doesn't make sense mathematically, and from a false premise you could reach a false conclusion. You better constrain your function in some other way. Try reading on conditional definitions here: [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)

Comment: Thanks! That should solve all my numerical optimization problems!

Comment: I did try to contain, say using Exp[x], which should be >0. But during the optimization, I still get 0.0^0.

Comment: @chen, maybe you can try changing `Power[0, 0] = 1` to `Power[0|0., 0|0.] = 1`.

Comment: $0^0=1$ does make sense mathematically. Just because $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^y$ is indeterminate does not mean that $0^0$ should be left undefined. In most practical cases, $0^0=1$ is what is wanted. We should simply note that $x^y$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Can one define 0 Log[0] = 1?

Comment: In some areas of math like combinatorics, $0^0 = 1$ is pretty much the standard interpretation, so it does make sense.

Comment: It's OK to *down-vote*, bit it would be nice to have a note explaining why.