# Can one define 0 Log[0] = 0?

Tags: variable-definitions, numerical-value

With reference to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64179/could-i-define-00-to-be-1), can one define `0 Log[0] = 0` in Mathemtica?

Comment: This might be an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That being said, I would use `Function[r, Piecewise[{{Log[r^r], 0 < r < 1}, {r Log[r], 1 < r}}, 0], Listable]`.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that in my code I have terms like x Log[x]; when x becomes very small, Mathematica shows indeterminate when it should show 0.

Comment: You might evaluate with `Limit[f, x -> x0]`.

Comment: The problem is that my function f involves many such terms (many different variables x), so I need a general rule which will automatically set x Log[x] = 0 for small x.

Comment: Is this for an entropy calculation?

Comment: ***IF*** the coefficient of `Log[x]` always vanishes with an order higher than some `x^r`, `r > 0`, as `x -> 0`, then the following should work: `log[x_?NumericQ /; x != 0] := Log[x]; expr /. Log -> log /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> 0.] /. log -> Log`. Some tweaking may be needed depending on the application.

Comment: A similar approach could be used with @J.M.'s function but defining `xlogx[x]` and replacing `expr /. Log -> (xlogx[#]/# &) // Simplify`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Inactive` here.

```
expr = (1 - x) Log[1 - x];
iexpr = expr /. Log -> Inactive[Log];
```

Now, insert a number, activate after numeric evaluation of everything but Log.

```
iexpr /. x -> -2. // Activate
(* 3.29584 *)
```

Because you've controlled the order of evaluation, the troublesome case becomes zero.

```
iexpr /. x -> 1. // Activate
(* 0. *)
```

`Activate` not needed in this special case, but harmless.

This works for exact numbers and machine numbers. For controlled precision, you'll need to do more.

Comment: This is similar to the approach in my comment, and probably should have the same priviso, "IF the coefficient of Log[x] always vanishes with an order higher than some x^r, r > 0, as x -> 0,..."

Answer (score 0):

You can define

```
s[0|0.] = 0;
s[x_] = -x*Log[x];
SetAttributes[s, Listable]
```

and then use the function `s` instead of `x Log[x]`. If you also have values of $x<0$ then other definitions should be added.

Comment: Thanks, @Roman. How can one put further restrictions like s[x]=0 for say x<10^(-15).

Comment: @TobiasFritzn take a look at the `Picewise` function.

Comment: I don't think you need to make a separate definition for, say, x<10^(-15), as the function x*log(x) is well-behaved around x=0. There's only really a need for a special definition at the very point x=0.