# Sum of powers of zero

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, algebra

I would like to calculate the following sum

`Sum[0^(k-a), {k, 0, Nin}]`

for a positive integer $a$.

With considering $0^0=1$, my expected answer of the sum is $1$, which is obtained for $k=a$, while ignoring the other terms for $k\neq a$.

Can this be made in Mathematica somehow?

Comment: Mathematica considers 0^0 to be indeterminate.

Comment: Since you want to arbitrarily equate the sum to `1` just use 

`Sum[0^(k - a), {k, 0, Nin}] /. _ -> 1`

Comment: 0^-1 is ComplexInfinity.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64180/30083.

Answer (score 1):

Use `KroneckerDelta[n]` or `DiscreteDelta[n]` instead of `0^n`.