# How to make the result of Piecewise be a closed interval?

Tags: piecewise, splines

#### Description

This question comes from two questions. Namely [Q1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71778/how-to-speed-up-the-plotting-of-b-spline-curve) and [Q2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63192/how-to-deal-with-the-condition-u-i-u-i1-in-b-spline-basis-function)

The defintion of B-Spline basis function as shown below:

Let $\vec{U}=\{u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ a nondecreasing sequence of real numbers,i.e, $u_i\leq u_{i+1}\quad i=0,1,2\ldots m-1$

$$N_{i,0}(u)=
\begin{cases}
   1 & u_i\leq u<u_{i+1}\\
   0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
$$
$$N_{i,p}(u)=\frac{u-u_i}{u_{i+p}-u_i}N_{i,p-1}(u)+\frac{u_{i+p+1}-u}{u_{i+p+1}-u_{i+1}}N_{i+1,p-1}(u)
$$

```
  NBSpline[i_Integer, 0, knots_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] && OrderedQ[#] &),u_] /;
   i <= Length[knots] - 2 :=
   Piecewise[
    {{1, knots[[i + 1]] <= u < knots[[i + 2]]}},0]

  coeff[u_, i_, j_, knots_] /; knots[[i]] == knots[[j]] := 0;
  coeff[u_, i_, j_, knots_] := (u - knots[[i]])/(knots[[j]] - knots[[i]])

  NBSpline[i_Integer, p_Integer, knots_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] && OrderedQ[#] &), 
    u_] /;p > 0 && i + p <= Length[knots] - 2 :=
   Module[{init, res},
    init = Table[NBSpline[j, 0, knots, u], {j, i, i + p}];
    res = First@
    Nest[
     Dot @@@
      (Thread@
        {Partition[#, 2, 1],
         With[{m = p + 2 - Length@#},
          Table[
           {coeff[u, k + 1, k + m + 1, knots],
            coeff[u, k + m + 2, k + 2, knots]}, {k, i, i + Length@# - 2}]]}) &,
    init, p]
  ]
```

#### Compare to *built-in* function `BSplineBasis`

```
 sortResult[x_ /; x == 0] := 0;
 sortResult[res_] := MapAt[SortBy[#, Last] &, res, 1]

 pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 0}, {6, 3}, {8, 2}, {8, 0}};
 knots = {0, 0, 0, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1, 1, 1};
```

**Comparsion 1**

```
 NBSpline[#, 0, knots, u] & /@ Range[0, 8] // Simplify
```

> [image]

```
 PiecewiseExpand@BSplineBasis[{0, knots}, #, u] & /@ Range[0, 8]
```

> [image]

**Comparsion 2**

```
sortResult /@ (NBSpline[#, 1, knots, u] & /@ Range[0, 7] // Simplify)
```

> [image]

```
sortResult /@ (PiecewiseExpand@BSplineBasis[{1, knots}, #, u] & /@ 
Range[0, 7] // Simplify)
```

> [image]

---

By the comparsion, I found that the result of `BSplineBasis` is always a `closed interval`, whereas the result my function `NBSpline` is a  `half closed- half open` interval.

**My trail:**

```
postProcess[res_ /; res == 0] := 0;

postProcess[res_] :=
 Module[{interval, pos, expr},
  interval =
   First@Simplify@res;
  pos =
   Position[
   SortBy[interval, Last], Less];
  expr =
   ReplacePart[
    SortBy[interval, Last], pos[[-1]] -> LessEqual];
  Piecewise[expr, 0]
]
```

**Test**

```
 postProcess /@ (NBSpline[#, 1, knots, u] & /@ Range[0, 7])
```

> [image]

#### Question:

Is there any good/simple method(strategy) to deal with this problem? I think my method is complex.

> [image]

Comment: I think you have correctly implemented the formula. try specially treating the last interval `If[ i<Length[knots]-2,Piecewise[..<],Piecewise[..<=]]`.

Comment: @george2079,This afternoon, I rewritten it as you said, however, it failed.From the result of *built-in* function `BSplineBasis`,I felt this *built-in* function makes the result become the `closed interval`.

Comment: Answering _"Is there any method/strategy to deal with this problem?"_ : `NBSpline[#, 0, knots, u] & /@ Range[0, 8] /.  Less :> LessEqual // Simplify`

Comment: @belisarius  If utilizing `/.  Less :> LessEqual`, which will make all the `sub-intervals` of inequalitys become the style of $[a,b]$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a fix, specially treating the end interval:

```
 NBSpline[i_Integer, 0, knots_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] && OrderedQ[#] &),
      u_] /; i <= Length[knots] - 2 := (
   If[ knots[[i + 2]] != knots[[-1]],
       Piecewise[{{1, knots[[i + 1]] <= u < knots[[i + 2]]}}, 0],
       Piecewise[{{1, knots[[i + 1]] <= u <= knots[[i + 2]]}}, 0] ]);
 coeff[u_, i_, j_, knots_] /; knots[[i]] == knots[[j]] := 0;
 coeff[u_, i_, j_, knots_] := (u - knots[[i]])/(knots[[j]] - knots[[i]])
 NBSpline[i_Integer, p_Integer, 
      knots_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] && OrderedQ[#] &), u_] /; 
           p > 0 && i + p <= Length[knots] - 2 := 
 Module[{init, res}, 
      init = Table[NBSpline[j, 0, knots, u], {j, i, i + p}];
      res = First@
      Nest[Dot @@@ (Thread@{Partition[#, 2, 1], 
          With[{m = p + 2 - Length@#}, 
              Table[{coeff[u, k + 1, k + m + 1, knots], 
              coeff[u, k + m + 2, k + 2, knots]}, {k, i, 
                  i + Length@# - 2}]]}) &, init, p]]
  pts = {{1/10, 2/10}, {0, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 0}, {6, 3}, {8, 2}, {8, 0}};
  knots = {0, 0, 0, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1, 1, 1};
  BSplinePlot1[pts : {{_, _} ..}, knots_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
  Module[{p = Length@First@Split[knots] - 1, a, b},
        {a, b} = {First[knots], Last[knots]};
    f[u_] = 
        Evaluate@
           Simplify@
               Total@MapIndexed[NBSpline[First@#2 - 1, p, knots, u] #1 &, 
                      pts] /. x_Piecewise :> Piecewise[x[[1]], Null];
    ParametricPlot[f[u], {u, a, b}, opts, PlotPoints -> 1000]]
    BSplinePlot1[pts, knots, ImageSize -> 600]
```

this bit: `/. x_Piecewise :> Piecewise[x[[1]], Null]` fixes the catchall behavior of `Piecewise` so you will get an error if you try to evaluate out of bounds. (not necessary for this example )

here is `f[u]` , note that we have closed just the end interval..

[image]

note as a practical matter @belisarius approach works as well, so long as you apply at the last stage:

```
 f[u_] = Evaluate@
          Simplify@
             Total@MapIndexed[NBSpline[First@#2 - 1, p, knots, u] #1 &, 
                pts] /. Less :> LessEqual /. x_Piecewise :> Piecewise[x[[1]], Null]
```

[image]

since the function is continuous it doesn't really matter if you close all the internal intervals.

Comment: Thanks for your help, In fact, I discovered a simple(but not good) method to avoid the point `{0,0}`. Namely, `ParametricPlot[f[u], {u, a, b-10^-3}]`