# How to implement a more efficient inverse triangular recursion?

Tags: programming, performance-tuning, recursion

Consider the following **inverse triangular** formula

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
   &   &   &   & N_{i-p,p}\left(u_0\right) \\
   &   & N_{i-2,2}\left(u_0\right) &   &   \\
   & N_{i-1,1}\left(u_0\right) &   &   &   \\
 \color{red}{N_{i,0}\left(u_0\right)=1} &   & N_{i-1,2}\left(u_0\right) & \cdots  & \vdots  \\
   & N_{i,1}\left(u_0\right) &   &   &   \\
   &   & N_{i,2}\left(u_0\right) &   &   \\
   &   &   &   & N_{i,p}\left(u_0\right)
\end{array}
\right)$$

where, $N_{i,0}=1$, and 
[image]

In addition, $u_0 \in [u_i,u_{i+1})$ `knots =` $\{u_0,u_1, \cdots, u_m\}, 0\leq u_i \leq u_j$

---

Here is a **procedural** implementaion calculate $\color{blue}{N_{i-p,p}(u_0),B_{i-p+1,p}(u_0), \cdots, N_{i,p}(u_0)}$

- Search the index $i$ by the auxiliary function `searchSpan`
- [image]

In the code, I use the following local array to store the values of $N_{m,n}$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
   &   &   &   & N_{i-p,p}\left(u_0\right) \\
   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   & N_{i-2,2}\left(u_0\right) &   & \vdots  \\
   & N_{i-1,1}\left(u_0\right) & N_{i-1,2}\left(u_0\right) & \cdots  &   \\
 N_{i,0}\left(u_0\right) & N_{i,1}\left(u_0\right) & N_{i,2}\left(u_0\right) & \cdots  & N_{i,p}\left(u_0\right)
\end{array}
\right)_{(p+1)\times (p+1)}
$$

where $N_{m,n}$ was stored in the position $(p+1-i+m,n+1)$ of local array

Search the index of span $[u_i,u_{i+1})$

```
searchSpan[{deg_, knots_}, u0_] :=
 Module[{biSearch},
  biSearch =
   Function[{low, high},
    With[{mid = Floor[(low + high)/2]}, 
     If[u0 < knots[[mid]], {low, mid}, {mid, high}]]
   ];(*Do bisection search*)
  First@
   NestWhile[
    biSearch[Sequence @@ #, u0] &,
    {deg + 1, Length@knots - deg}, Subtract @@ # != -1 &] - 1
]
```

---

```
NonzeroBasis[{deg_, knots_}, u0_] :=
 Module[{coeff, basis, i},
  coeff =
   (u0 - knots[[#1 + 1]])/(knots[[#1 + #2 + 1]] - knots[[#1 + 1]]) &;
  basis = ConstantArray[1, {deg + 1, deg + 1}];
  i = searchSpan[{deg, knots}, u0];
  Do[
   basis[[deg + 1 - k, k + 1]] =
    (1 - coeff[i - k + 1, k]) basis[[deg + 2 - k, k]];
   With[{m = deg + 1 - i},
    Do[
     basis[[m + j, k + 1]] =
      {coeff[j, k], 1 - coeff[j + 1, k]}.{basis[[m + j, k]], basis[[m + j + 1, k]]},
     {j, i - k + 1, i - 1}]
    ];
   basis[[deg + 1, k + 1]] =
    coeff[i, k] basis[[deg + 1, k]],
   {k, deg}];
   basis
 ]
```

#### Test

```
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
deg = 4;
NonzeroBasis[{deg, knots}, 5/2] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{288} \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{48} & \frac{227}{1152} \\
>  1 & 1 & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{23}{48} & \frac{205}{384} \\
>  1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{15}{32} & \frac{25}{96} \\
>  1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{32} & \frac{1}{192}
> \end{array}
> \right)$

---

#### Performance test

```
knots0 = 
 Join[ConstantArray[0, 3001], Range[1, 5000], ConstantArray[5001, 3001]];
deg0 = 3000;
NonzeroBasis[{deg0, knots0}, 2.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

#### Question

- How to implement this `triangular formula` in a non-procedural(like **functional** or **rule-based**) method?
- How to improve the **efficience** of `NonzeroBasis`?

---

#### Update

Another example I found today was the calculation of *Bernstein* function

$$B_{n,i}(u)=\binom n i u^i(1-u)^{n-i}$$, where $0 \leq u \leq 1$

In addition, *Bernstein* function owns the following recursive relationship:

$$B_{n,i}(u)=(1-u) B_{n-1,i}(u)+uB_{n-1,i-1}(u)$$

where, $B_{n,i}(u)=0$ when $i<0$ or $i>n$

So we can use the following triangular schematic digram to calculate $\color{blue}{B_{n,0}(u),B_{n,0}(u), \cdots, B_{n,n}(u)}$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & B_{n,0} (u) \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & .\cdot{}^{\cdot} & \text{} \\
 \text{} & \text{} & B_{2,0}(u)& \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{} & B_{1,0} (u) & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \color{red}{B_{0,0} (u)=1} & \text{} & B_{2,1}(u)& \vdots  & \vdots  \\
 \text{} & B_{1,0}(u) & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{} & \text{} & B_{2,2}(u)& \text{ } & \text{} \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \ddots & \text{} \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & B_{n,n} (u) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Related question**

- [Alternative ways to implement a triangular recursion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/alternative-ways-to-implement-a-triangular-recursion)
- [How to speed up the plotting of B-spline curve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71778/how-to-speed-up-the-plotting-of-b-spline-curve/72180#72180)

Comment: I find your explanation confusing. Not blaming, perhaps I just need another point of view. Do you perchance have any link explaining the "inverse triangular recursion"?

Comment: @belisarius, Sorry for my confusing description. In J.M's [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/alternative-ways-to-implement-a-triangular-recursion), **triangular recursion** owns the following style $$\begin{array}{}T_0^{(0)}&T_1^{(0)}&T_2^{(0)}&T_3^{(0)}\\T_0^{(1)}&T_1^{(1)}&T_2^{(1)}&\\T_0^{(2)}&T_1^{(2)}&&\\T_0^{(3)}&&&\end{array}$$So I add a prefix *inverse* before the **triangular recursion** to distinguish them.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. Is `knots` always a sorted array? 2. Is the exact result necessary i.e. `MachinePrecision` real number can't be used?

Comment: @xzczd, (1) Yes, `knots` is always a sorted vector  that owns the style $\{u_0,u_1,\cdots, u_m\}$, where, $0 \leq u_i \leq u_j$ (2) No, the`MachinePrecision`real number could be used. In addition, I tried the `Compile`, but it failed.

Comment: 3. Why your `searchSpan` outputs `6` for `5/2`? I think it'll be better to make it output `7`, so we can implement the definition at the beginning directly. Currently, something like `coelist = With[{u = knots, p = deg}, 
  Table[{(u0 - u[[j]])/(u[[j + k]] - u[[j]]), 
    1 - (u0 - u[[j + 1]])/(u[[j + k + 1]] - u[[j + 1]])}, {k, 1, p}, {j, i - k, 
    i}]]` won't give the correct result.

Comment: @xzczd, `searchSpan` outputs `6` for `5/2` is right. Because $5/2 \in [2,3)$ in `knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};` and $u_6=2$. Here, the first $0$ in `knots` is $u_0$, not $u_1$

Comment: …OK, I see, but personally I think beginning from $0$ isn't very convenient here, and there's already another $u_0$ in the formula, right?

Comment: @xzczd, Um, I use the symbol  `u0`  to denonte the value of the varible $u$, rather than the first value of `knots`.:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, to be honest, despite I've been using *Mathematica* for 3 years, I'm getting more and more confused about what's functional programming, but the following solution is at least more elegant and faster than yours:

```
searchSpan2[knots_, u0_] := First@Ordering[UnitStep[u0 - knots], 1] - 1

NonzeroBasis2[p_, u_, u0_] :=
 With[
  {i = searchSpan2[u, u0],
   coeff = (u0 - u[[#1]])/(u[[#1 + #2]] - u[[#1]]) &},
  FoldList[
   MapThread[Dot, {#2, Partition[#, 2, 1, {-1, 1}, 0]}] &,
   {1}, Table[{coeff[j, k], 1 - coeff[j + 1, k]}, {k, 1, p}, {j, i - k, i}]
  ]
 ]

NonzeroBasis[{deg0, knots0}, 2.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
NonzeroBasis2[deg0, knots0, 2.5]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {76.629522, Null} *)
(* {35.073471, Null} *)
```

Notice that the output of my `searchSpan2` equals to that of `searchSpan2` plus 1, and the result is a triangular array, which can't be compiled directly.

Then, for the performance part, I failed to figure out how to compile your `NonzeroBasis`, but managed to write a compiled version myself:

```
NonzeroBasis3 =
  ReleaseHold[
   Hold@
     Compile[{{p, _Integer}, {u, _Real, 1}, {u0, _Real}}, 
      With[{i = searchSpan2[u, u0]},
       Module[{lst = Table[0., {i + 1}, {p + 1}]},
        lst[[i, 1]] = 1.;
        Do[
         lst[[j, k + 1]] = 
          (u0 - u[[j]])/(u[[j + k]] - u[[j]]) lst[[j, k]] + 
          (1 - (u0 - u[[j + 1]])/(u[[j + k + 1]] - u[[j + 1]])) lst[[j + 1, k]], 
         {k, p}, {j, i - k, i}];
        lst]
       ]
     ] /. DownValues@searchSpan2];
        

NonzeroBasis3[deg0, knots0, 2.5]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.093708, Null} *)
```

Notice the structures of the results are not the same:

```
MatrixForm /@ Through[{NonzeroBasis[{#, #2}, #3] &, 
                       NonzeroBasis2, NonzeroBasis3}[deg, knots, 5/2]] // Row
```

[image]

---

### Update

OK, seems that I'm a little tired yesterday, your `NonzeroBasis` isn't hard to compile, we just need to:

1. Take the pure function `coeff` out of `Compile` and introduce it with a `With` outside. Pure function can be used in `Compile`, but it can't exist on its own. The type of variables inside `Compile` is limited to `_Integer`, `_Real`, `_Complex`, `True|False`, Just as the arguments of it.
2. Change the `ConstantArray[1, {deg + 1, deg + 1}]` into `ConstantArray[1., {deg + 1, deg + 1}]` because `basis` should be a `Real` type array. (`ConstantArray` isn't compiled actually but it's not a big deal here. You can use `Table`, as I did in `NonzeroBasis3` though.)
3. Simply use `searchSpan2` instead of `searchSpan`, mainly based on my personal preference. (Your `searchSpan` also need to be modified if you want to compile it. It's not hard to take it out of `Compile`, of course. )

Here's the compiled `NonzeroBasis`:

```
(* This line is just to tell you a truth: *)
knots = aaa; u0 = bbb;

compiledNonzeroBasis = 
 With[{coeff = (u0 - knots[[#1 + 1]])/(knots[[#1 + #2 + 1]] - knots[[#1 + 1]]) &}, 
  ReleaseHold[
    Hold@Compile[{{deg, _Integer}, {knots, _Real, 1}, {u0, _Real}}, 
       Module[{basis = ConstantArray[1., {deg + 1, deg + 1}], 
               i = searchSpan2[knots, u0] - 1},
        
        Do[basis[[deg + 1 - k, k + 1]] = (1 - coeff[i - k + 1, k]) basis[[deg + 2 - k, k]];
         With[{m = deg + 1 - i}, 
          Do[basis[[m + j, k + 1]] = {coeff[j, k], 
              1 - coeff[j + 1, k]}.{basis[[m + j, k]], basis[[m + j + 1, k]]}, {j, 
            i - k + 1, i - 1}]];
         basis[[deg + 1, k + 1]] = coeff[i, k] basis[[deg + 1, k]], {k, deg}];
        basis]] /. DownValues@searchSpan2]];

knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};    
compiledNonzeroBasis[deg0, knots0, 2.5]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.437518, Null} *)
```

And, if speed is really concerned, here's a optimized version of my `NonzeroBasis3`(Notice that a C compiler is necessary):

```
(* This line is just to tell you a truth: *)
u = aaa; u0 = bbb;

With[{g = Compile`GetElement}, 
  coeff[x1_, x2_] := (u0 - g[u, x1])/(g[u, x1 + x2] - g[u, x1]);
  optimizedNonzeroBasis3 = 
   ReleaseHold[
    Hold@Compile[{{p, _Integer}, {u, _Real, 1}, {u0, _Real}}, 
        With[{i = searchSpan2[u, u0]}, 
         Module[{lst = Table[0., {i + 1}, {p + 1}]}, lst[[i, 1]] = 1.;
          Do[
           lst[[j, k + 1]] = 
            coeff[j, k] g[lst, j, k] + (1 - coeff[j + 1, k]) g[lst, j + 1, k], 
            {k, p}, {j, i - k, i}];
          lst]], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
      DownValues@searchSpan2 /. DownValues@coeff]];

optimizedNonzeroBasis3[deg0, knots0, 2.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.124957, Null} *)
```

Comment: In the function `NonzeroBasis3`, when I replace `lst[[j, k + 
    1]] = (u0 - u[[j]])/(u[[j + k]] - u[[j]]) lst[[j, 
     k]] + (1 - (u0 - u[[j + 1]])/(u[[j + k + 1]] - 
        u[[j + 1]])) lst[[j + 1, k]]` with `lst[[j, k + 1]] =
 coeff[j, k] lst[[j, k]] + (1 - coeff[j + 1, k] ) lst[[j + 1, k]]`, here `coeff = (u0 - u[[#1]])/(u[[#1 + #2]] - u[[#1]]) &` in the `Module` enviroment, however, it failed. Could you tell me why?THX:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot:). I am not familiar with `Compile`, so your code is very helpful for me.

Comment: For the auxiliary fuction `searchSpan[]`, Please see my edit in [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91610/how-to-implement-a-more-efficient-inverse-triangular-recursion/91666#91666)

Comment: Maybe a bug. `knots1 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,10};` then `searchSpan2[knots1, 10]
searchSpan[{2, knots1}, 10]`

Comment: @ShutaoTang `knots1` doesn't fit the description, right? $u_0 \in [u_i,u_{i+1})$ so $u_i<u_{i+1}$.

Comment: OK, I see. The last element is a **special case** Thanks!

Comment: @ShutaoTang If the last element needs special treatment, you can use something like `searchSpan2[knots_, u0_] := First@Ordering[Sign[u0 - knots], 1] + If[knots[[-1]] == u0, 1, -1]`

Comment: Ok, maybe I need to consider refactor the `searchSpan`:)

Comment: @xzczd you can use the CompileExpand function from the following answer instead of replacing DownValues. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24596/66

Comment: @faysou Actually I know (and have already upvoted) this answer for years, but was not skilled enough to understand and use that function :)

Comment: It's quite powerful when you realize what it can do.

Comment: The key innovation that allowed the CompileExpand function is the Step function from Mr Wizard.

Comment: @faysou Actually this elegant yet abstruse function was one of the main barrier for my understanding 囧. It took me quite a while to figure out the meaning of `P = (P = …` today (after using _Mathematica_ for more than 4 years! ).