# How to generate a closed B-spline curve?

Tags: graphics, programming, splines

I wrote a function called [`deBoor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71778/how-to-speed-up-the-plotting-of-b-spline-curve/89612#89612) using the [Cox-de Boor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm) algorithm to generate a B-spline curve.

```
(*Search the index of span [ui,ui+1)*)
searchSpan[knots_, u0_] :=
 With[{max = Max[knots]},
  If[u0 == max,
   Position[knots, max][[1, 1]] - 2,
   Ordering[UnitStep[u0 - knots], 1][[1]] - 2]
]
(*The definition of α coefficient*)
α[{deg_, knots_}, {j_, k_}, u0_] /; 
  knots[[j + deg + 2]] == knots[[j + k + 1]] := 0
α[{deg_, knots_}, {j_, k_}, u0_] := 
  (u0 - knots[[j + k + 1]])/(knots[[j + deg + 2]] - knots[[j + k + 1]])

(*Implementation of de Boor algorithm*)
deBoor[pts : {{_, _} ..}, {deg_, knots_}, u0_] := 
 Module[{calcNextGroup, idx = searchSpan[knots, u0]},
  calcNextGroup =
   Function[{points, k},
    Module[{coords, coeffs},
     coords = Partition[points, 2, 1];
     coeffs = {1 - #, #} & /@ (α[{deg, knots}, {#, k + 1}, u0] & /@
      Range[idx - deg, idx - k - 1]);
     {Plus @@@ MapThread[Times, {coords, coeffs}], k + 1}]
  ];
  Nest[calcNextGroup[Sequence @@ #] &,
   {pts[[idx - deg + 1 ;; idx + 1]], 0}, deg][[1, 1]]
]
```

#### TEST

```
points = 
 {{1, 4}, {.5, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 12}, {11, 14}, {8, 4}, {12, 3}, {11, 9}, {15, 10}, {17, 8}};
(*here, I set the knots uniformly*)
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/7, 2/7, 3/7, 4/7, 5/7, 6/7, 1, 1, 1, 1};

ParametricPlot[
  deBoor[points, {3, knots}, t], {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Now, I need to close this curve. My first thought is append the **first point** to the `pts` list.

```
pointsCLOSE = 
 {{1, 4}, {.5, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 12}, {11, 14}, {8, 4}, {12, 3}, 
  {11, 9}, {15, 10}, {17, 8}, {1, 4}};
(*here, I set the knots uniformly*)
knotsCLOSE = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/8, 2/8, 3/8, 4/8, 5/8, 6/8, 7/8, 1, 1, 1, 1};
ParametricPlot[
 deBoor[pointsCLOSE, {3, knotsCLOSE}, t], {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

However, the *built-in* `BSplineCurve` gives a different curve

```
Graphics[{BSplineCurve[points, SplineClosed -> True]}]
```

[image]

#### The comparison of two graphics

[image]

So my thought is wrong

In the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23785702#23785702), thanks to [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan)'s suggestion

> For this closed form, you need to assume the endpoints to be periodic. It is not enough to just pre-/append one point.

#### QUESTION

- What does the **the endpoints to be periodic** mean? I didn't learn it from [*The NURBS Book*](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-59223-2/page/1)
- How to generate a closed B-spline curve like the *built-in* `BSplineCurve[pts, SplineClosed -> True]` ?

#### UPDATE

```
uniformKnots[pts_, deg_] :=
 With[{n = Length@pts},
  Join[
   ConstantArray[0, deg + 1],
   Range[1, n - deg - 1]/(n - deg),
   ConstantArray[1, deg + 1]]
  ]

Manipulate[
 With[{pts = Join[points, points[[1 ;; n]]]},
  ParametricPlot[
   deBoor[pts, {3, uniformKnots[pts, 3]}, t], {t, 0, 1}, 
   Axes -> False]], {n, 1, 10, 1}
]
```

[image]

- I didn't **how many** points should I append to the original points list?

Comment: I think you can think of endpoint-periodic like the `PeriodicInterpolation` for `Interpolation`.

Comment: @Silvia, thanks a lot :) According to your hint,  I copy the entire points to the last position of `pts list`. Namely, `pointsCLOSE1 = {{1, 4}, {.5, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 12}, {11, 14}, {8, 4}, {12, 3}, {11, 9}, {15, 10}, {17, 8}, {1, 4}, {.5, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 12}, {11, 14}, {8, 4}, {12, 3}, {11, 9}, {15, 10}, {17, 8}};
knotsCLOSE1 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/17, 2/17, 3/17, 4/17, 5/17, 6/17, 7/17, 8/17, 9/17, 10/17, 11/17, 12/17, 13/17, 14/17, 15/17, 16/17, 1, 1, 1, 1};ParametricPlot[deBoor[pointsCLOSE1, {3, knotsCLOSE1}, t], {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]`

Comment: @Silvia  which gernerates a curve like **built-in**, please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WVZIf.png) Obviously, the entire points that adding to the last posotion is too many. I would like to know `how many` **points** did I need to add? THX:)

Comment: Good to know :) Though I think there should be easier way by manipulating the knots' weights.

Comment: @Silvia, The `knots`sequence own this style $\{u_0, u_1,\cdots,u_m\}$, `points` own the style $\{P_0,P_1,\cdots,P_n\}$. In addtion the `degree` of B-spline curve is $p$, so they own the following relationship $$n+1+p=m$$ In general, the knots is **uniform**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following works for your curve:

```
points = {{1, 4}, {.5, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 12}, {11, 14}, {8, 4}, {12, 3}, {11, 9},
          {15, 10}, {17, 8}};
deg = 3; 
pointsCLOSE1 = Join[points, points];
n = Length@pointsCLOSE1;
knotsCLOSE1 = Range[0, 1, 1/(n + 1)];
ParametricPlot[deBoor[pointsCLOSE1, {deg, knotsCLOSE1}, t], {t, deg/(n + 1), 1}, 
               Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And also for many other curves

```
curve[nPts_, deg_] := Module[{points, pointsCLOSE1, n, knotsCLOSE1},
  points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {nPts, 2}]; 
  pointsCLOSE1 = Join[points, points];
  n = Length@pointsCLOSE1;
  knotsCLOSE1 = Range[0, 1, 1/(n + 1)];
  ParametricPlot[ deBoor[pointsCLOSE1, {deg, knotsCLOSE1}, t], 
                  {t, deg/(n + 1), 1}, Axes -> False]
  ]

degs = RandomInteger[{3, 6}, 6];
npoints = RandomInteger[{2 #, 3 #}] & /@ degs;
Partition[MapThread[curve, {npoints, degs}], 3] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I've also found some counterexamples, so it should be taken with care ...

Comment: About the NURBS, in general, for a curve of degree $p$, the `knots` owns the following style $$\{u_0,\cdots,u_p,u_{p+1},\cdots, u_{m-p},\cdots, u_m\}$$ where $u_0=\cdots=u_p=0$ and $u_{m-p}=\cdots=u_m=1$. So I'd like to know **why** you *set* the `knots` to `Range[0, 1, 1/(n + 1)]` and changed the interval to `[deg/(n + 1), 1]`. THX  a lot:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang I tried a few things until it worked. Sorry, zero NURBS knowledge here :)

Comment: I would like to know what method did you used to achieve the right result. Especially for the setting `knotsCLOSE1 = Range[0, 1, 1/(n + 1)];`
 and `{t, deg/(n + 1), 1}`,   very apperciate it:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang Just luck. I made a cursory browse at a few web pages about NURBS and thought that those may work. Anyway, I'm sure that it isn't completely right. I made up some examples resulting in open curves

Comment: I cannot understand this sentence`Wrap the first $p$ and last $p$ control points`

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have missed this earlier. Anyway, creating a closed spline in *Mathematica* explicitly is actually rather simple. Witness the following:

```
pts = {{1, 4}, {.5, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 12}, {11, 14}, {8, 4}, {12, 3}, {11, 9},
       {15, 10}, {17, 8}};

m = 5; (* degree *) n = Length[pts];
f = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> m];

fn = BSplineFunction[ArrayPad[pts, {{0, m}, {0, 0}}, "Periodic"], 
                     SplineDegree -> m, 
                     SplineKnots -> ArrayPad[Subdivide[n], m, "Extrapolated"]];
```

See the correspondence:

```
ParametricPlot[{f[t], fn[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
               PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[6], AbsoluteThickness[2]}]
```

[image: matched periodic splines]

Further proof of correspondence can be seen by trying `ParametricPlot[f[t] - fn[t], {t, 0, 1}]`.

Another example:

```
pts = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1},
       {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}};
n = Length[pts];
f = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True];
fn = BSplineFunction[ArrayPad[pts, {{0, 3}, {0, 0}}, "Periodic"], 
                     SplineKnots -> ArrayPad[Subdivide[n], 3, "Extrapolated"]];

{ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 1}], ParametricPlot3D[fn[t], {t, 0, 1}]}
// GraphicsRow
```

[image: two identical 3D B-splines]

Comment: Thanks J.M. In fact, I known the `BSplineCurve[pts, SplineClosed -> True]` could generate a `closed B-spline`. Firstly, I tried the method mentioned [here](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-closed.html)。 However, it failed. I understood the theory of  `closed B-spline` until I read the `section 12.2` of **The NURBS Book** occasionally.

Comment: Right, so pay attention to what I did to the knots and control points. :)

Comment: Yes, I have attentioned the `control points` and `knots` that you specified in `BSplineFunction`. BTW, how did you know the  `control points` and `knots`that generating a `closed B-spline`? Namely, I would like to know which **paper** or **textbook** describes this in detail. :)

Comment: I'll need to look up which refs have them; will ping you as soon as I find them.

Comment: Ah, there... the uniform knot vector presented in Shutao's answer and this answer seems a bit... different. His solution extrapolates only at the end; mine extends both the beginning and the end of the uniform knot vector. I suppose they are equivalent up to scaling, tho.