# Trying to build a function to compute divided difference for arbitrary list of points

Tags: interpolation, recursion

As the title says Im trying to build a function to compute divided difference for arbitrary list of points.

The divided difference of a set of points $\{(x_1,y_1),\ldots, (x_n,y_n)\}$ where $x_j<x_{j+1}$ is defined recursively by

$$
f[i,j]:=\frac{f[i+1,j]-f[i,j-1]}{x_j-x_i},\, f[i,i]:=y_i
$$

for $j\ge i$.I tried to mimic this definition with the code

```
f[i_, j_, m_] := f[i, j, m] = (f[i + 1, j, m] - f[i, j - 1, m])/(
m[[j, 1]] - m[[i, 1]]) Boole[j > i] + m[[j, 2]] Boole[j == i]
```

where `m` is an arbitrary $n\times 2$ matrix. However I tried to see if this works calling `f[1,1,{{1,2},{3,4}}]`but it gives me a recursion limit error. How I can fix the above code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In recursive definitions, you need to specify a one or more stopping definitions. E.g. for the factorial function `f[0] = 1; f[n_] := n f[n - 1]` from the docs almost works, but better is something like `f[0] = 1; f[n_Integer?Positive] := n f[n - 1]` or `f[0] = 1; f[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := n f[n - 1]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 but these stops are already defined in the function, when you can something where $j=i$

Comment: FWIW, here's a procedural def. based on the algorithm in Atkinson, *Intro. to Num. Anal.*: `dividedDifference[x_, f_] := Module[{d},
  With[{n = Length[(x)]},
   d = f; (* div. diff. computed in place *)
   Do[
    d[[j]] = (d[[j]] - d[[j - 1]])/(x[[j]] - x[[j - k + 1]]),
    {k, 2, n}, {j, n, k, -1}];
   d
   ]]` -- `x` is a list of nodes and `f` a list of values at the nodes. For input `m`, the call should be `dividedDifference @@ Transpose@m`.

Comment: Masacroso, you show only one definition rule for `f[i_, j_, m_]`, which calls `f[i + 1, j, m]` and `f[i, j - 1, m]`, both of which in turn call `f` on new arguments ad infinitum. Unless there are definition rules that you are not showing, there are no stops to this process. The calls to `f` will occur even if `Boole[]` evaluates to zero, in case you think `Boole[]` might stop the process.  It would be possible to put the stops in using an `If[]` statement.

Comment: @MichaelE2 OK, I thought that the `Boole` function would stop it, but it doesn't. I will try to fix it with an `If` statement as you said

Comment: @Michael's implementation is in fact a *[triangular recursion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1691)*, and is really the most efficient method to build up the divided difference table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, instead of evaluating an individual entry as $ f_{ij} $ once at a time, here I provide an implementation generating the whole upper-triangular $ f $ matrix. So here we go:

```
Clear[fmat]
fmat[pts : {{_, _} ..}] := Module[{n = Length[pts], kernels, xs, ys, denomenators, entries},
                                  {xs, ys} = pts\[Transpose]; 
                                  kernels = NestList[Insert[#, 0, 2] &, {-1, 1}, n - 2];
                                  denomenators = ListCorrelate[#, xs] & /@ kernels;
                                  entries = FoldList[Differences[#]/#2 &, ys, denomenators];
                                  SparseArray[MapIndexed[Band[Prepend[#2, 1]] -> # &, entries], n]
                                 ]
```

To check its validity, one can see a symbolic result and compare it with that on the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences):

[image]

Then below calculation is trivial

[image]

Also, I have tested on lists of random reals with a larger shape, say $ 1000\times 2 $. The efficiency of generating the $ 1000\times 1000 $ $ f $ matrix is acceptable, at least.

---

**P.S.**
I learnt that the calculation of divided difference is related to Newton interpolation. So if your purpose is to do so interpolations, you can directly use built-in functions like `Interpolation`, `InterpolatingPolynomial`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[dividedDif]
dividedDif = NestList[#/(#[[1, 1]] + #[[-1, -1]] &[Denominator /@ (List @@ #)]) & /@ 
     Differences[#] &, Divide @@ (Differences /@ #), Length[#[[1]]] - 2][[All, 1 ]] &;

Prepend[dividedDif @ #, #[[1, 1]]] & @ {{r, s, t, u, v}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice result, but I think you meant to write "dividedDif" on the last line with the Prepend.  When I do that, I get the answer you show.  Oddly, if you use the values {{1,2},{3,4}}, you don't get what was in the previous answer although I might have input that incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you @MarkR. Fixed it.