# Newton's divided differences iteration

Tags: interpolation, polynomials, iteration

I am trying to write a program that forms the interpolation polynomial for a given function on a given interval for any number of data points n. I wish to write a formula that will compute all of the necessary divided differences. Here is part of my code,

```
g[x_] := 1/(1 + x^2) 
f = Table[g[x], {x, -5.0, 5.0, 1}]
x = Table[a, {a, -5, 5, 1}]
 
Table[(f[[i]] - f[[i - 1]])/(x[[i + j]] - x[[i - 1]]), {j, 0, 9}, {i, 2, 11 - j}]
```

For `j=0` I get a list of the correct outputs I need, `{0.020362, 0.0411765, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, -0.5, -0.3, -0.1, -0.0411765,-0.020362}` but for `j=1`, I must find a way to have the terms in the numerator replaced with these output values over the loop, and so forth for each `j`. So for `j=1,i=2` I wish to write a formula that will calculate `(0.0411765-0.020362)/(x[[3]] - x[[1]])` for example, if this is possible.

I am a Mathematica novice, so bear with me and I hope I have been as clear as possible. I would appreciate any help, tips, tricks or guidance if it seems my approach is not a good one.

Comment: I don't if this is just a (homework) exercise, but if you want to use Mathematica, either `InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose@{xx, ff}, x]` or `Interpolation[Transpose@{xx, ff}, InterpolationOrder -> All][x]` constructs the interpolation you seek.

Comment: Yeah, this is part of an assignment. I am aware of the built-in interpolation but my professor explicitly mentioned not to use them and to "get our hands dirty a bit." I am able to write something but it is highly impractical and essentially impossible for large amounts of data points. I essentially wrote an entirely new function for each `j`, calling the results from the previous outputs.

Comment: Is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202832/12924) what you need?

Comment: I've seen this post, and it obviously produces the result that I am looking for. I was just interested in understanding whether my approach was a valid one or not, or whether my work could be adjusted to produce the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility (although a bit a tricky one):

We first define a function that returns the Newton polynomial as a function :

```
getNewton[xs_, ys_] := Module[{dd, i, newtoncoef},
  dd[{i_Integer}] := ys[[i]] ;(*dd implements Newton recursion*)
  dd[i : {__} ] := (dd[ Rest@i] - dd[Most@i])/(xs[[Last@i]] - 
      xs[[First@i]]);
  
  newtoncoef = 
   dd[Range[#]] & /@ Range[Length[xs]];(*Newton coefficients*)
  Function[x, newtoncoef.FoldList[#1 (x - #2) &, 1, Most@xs]]
  ]
```

Now we try it out. We first create some data and then apply our function to the x values:

```
g[x_] := 1/(1 + x^2);
ys = Table[g[x], {x, -5.0, 5.0, 1}];
xs = Table[x, {x, -5, 5, 1}];
Print["xs=", xs]; Print["ys=", ys];


Print["Newton poly at data points= ", getNewton[xs, ys] /@ xs]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated. I tried running this code, but rather than printing me the Newton polynomial, it printed a list of `ys` values.

Comment: @Sandwiches29 That is correct. getNewton does everything in one go. The coefficients are calculated by: "newtoncoef". getNewton1 will return the coefficients: getNewton1[xs_, ys_] := 
 Module[{dd, i, newtoncoef}, 
  dd[{i_Integer}] := ys[[i]];(*dd implements Newton recursion*)
  dd[i : {__}] := (dd[Rest@i] - dd[Most@i])/(xs[[Last@i]] - 
      xs[[First@i]]);
  newtoncoef = dd[Range[#]] & /@ Range[Length[xs]]
  ]