# Trying to implement Newton's interpolation polynomial - not evaluating divided differences

Tags: function-construction, interpolation

I'm trying to find Newton's interpolation polynomial for a given function and a set of points. However, I'm having some issues with finding the divided differences (in this case I've notated them with `R`) with nested `Do` expressions and iterating over the difference in indices between the first and last point. Whenever I run it for x != y, simply `R[x, y]` is printed.

```
n = 6;
(* Given function *)
f[x_] := 1/(1 + 4 x);
(* Given points *)
Do[x[k] = 0.5*k, {k, 0, n}];

(* f[x_i] = f(x_i) *)
Do[R[i_, i_] := f[x[i]], {i, 0, n}];

(* f[x_0, ... , x_n] = *)
(* (f[x_1, ... , x_n] - f[x_0, ... , x_n-1]) / (x_n - x_0) *)
Do[
  Do[R[i_, i_ + d_] = (R[i + 1, i + d] - R[i, i + d - 1]) / (x[i + d] - x[i]),
  {i, 0, n - d}],
{d, 1, n}];

Prod[t_, 0] = 1;
Do[Prod[t_, k_] := Product[(t - x[l]), {l, 0, k - 1}], {k, 0, n}];

L[f_, t_] := Sum[R[0, k]*Prod[t, k], {k, 0, n}];

(R[1, 1] - R[0, 0])/(x[1] - x[0])
R[0, 1]
```

And yes, I know there is a function for interpolating polynomials, I'm trying to accomplish finding the polynomial without it.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202818)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer for your problem, nor the most efficient approach, but...

This shows how easily the idea of Newton divided differences may be expressed in *Mathematica* (the formula was lifted from your code-comment, which inspired this approach).

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + 4 x);
Internal`InheritedBlock[{f},
 f[x0_, xx___, xn_] := (f[xx, xn] - f[x0, xx])/(xn - x0);
 f @@ (0.5 Range[0, 6])
 ]
(*  0.03031043031043034` *)
```

Check with `InterpolatingPolynomial`:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[{#, f[#]}] &[0.5 Range[0, 6]], x];
Level[%, {2*6}]
(*  {0.03031043031043036`, -1.` + x}  *)
```